# Compare two dates using valueOf()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, date

```
 const startDayOfTheWeek: number = moment().startOf('isoweek' as moment.unitOfTime.StartOf).valueOf();
 if (this.card.dateScheduled.valueOf() < startDayOfTheWeek) {
     this.card.dateScheduled = this.card.dateDue;
 }
```

When using `valueOf()`, `this.card.dateScheduled.valueOf()` this gives me a value of the actual date. Not the millisecond relative to 1970 (a.k.a the Unix timestamp/epoch).

Why is that?

Comment: What does "gives me a value of the actual date" mean and how do you verify what the value is?

Comment: it gives me the actual value of datescheduled. ex"2019-04-10T16:00:00Z" But when the value of datescheduled is "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" it gives me 0 using the value of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In moment.js there are many useful methods for comparing dates like `isAfter`, `isBefore`. So in your case use:

```
if (moment(this.card.dateScheduled).isBefore(startDayOfTheWeek))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take the benefits of inbuilt functionality.

Here is an example to compare dates in `javascript`.

```js
const first = +new Date(); // current date
const last = +new Date(2014, 10, 10); // old date 

console.log(first);
console.log(last);
// comparing the dates
console.log(first > last);
console.log(first < last);
```